# After Devise sign_in(user) current_user is nil for a while

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I am using omniAuth + facebook authentication

```
@user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
  if @user.persisted?

    @user.reload
    sign_in @user, :event => :authentication

    redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(@user)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
```

After facebook signIn, user lands on root url, when try to open /account/profile gives unauthorized error. But after a few seconds /account/profile becomes accessible. Why there is a delay here?

```
   class AccountController < ApplicationController
     layout false
     def profile

       if !current_user
         render status: 401
         return
       end
     end
```